# MATLAB GPU - Latency of CUDA memory copies?

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, latency

I am trying to measure the latencies of CUDA memory copies in MATLAB.
I wrote the following routine, where a scalar is repeatedly copied to and from the GPU.

```
a=single(randn(1,1));

tic;
for j=1:50*1000

    aGpu=gpuArray(a);
    a2=gather(aGpu);

end
toc;
```

The execution time is approximately one second. Given that there are 50,000 iterations in the loop and my CPU works at 3.4/3.7 GHz, this means that copying a scalar back and forth takes approximately 70,000 CPU cycles on average. I am only copying a scalar, so I guess that the time to transfer the data is negligible and most of the time employed is latency.
This kind of latency seems excessively high to me. I have read in various places that the latency of a CUDA memory copy is to be expected below 1,000 CPU cycles.
Has anybody done similar experiments? Are my numbers strange? Is it a problem with MATLAB? Are there things that need to be set up in the system/GPU configuration in order to reduce latencies?

More details: I am working with Windows 7, Matlab 2014a, on an Intel i7 and a GTX770 GeForce GPU.

Comment: Interesting question. Remember always: the bottleneck in GPU is in  comunication between CPU-GPU. Very often GPU is not worth because the CPU takes more time comunicating with the GPU than it would actually take to compute the problem. Try asking something more computationally expensive to the GPU.

Comment: Is there a reason why the latency of transferring one scalar to the GPU is of concern? When you launch a kernel you can include scalars that are transferred to the GPU at launch time. This could help hide that latency, however if you are worried about the latency of a GPU kernel, you likely need to do more work per kernel launched, as Ander Biguri was implying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you are measuring two memory copies, and it turns out that they are running in ~ 10 us each - which I actually think is not too bad at all (remembering that memory copies have essentially the same overhead as a kernel launch). For example, the following two papers estimate a latency of about 10 microseconds: 1) [Reducing GPU Offload Latency via Fine-Grained CPU-GPU Synchronization](https://www.princeton.edu/~dlustig/dlustig_HPCA13.pdf); 2) [Latency and Bandwidth Impact on GPU-systems](http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~elster/master-studs/runejoho/ms-proj-gpgpu-latency-bandwidth.pdf)

Comment: For the reference, see http://forum.seco.com/post/cudamemcpy-timings-varies-over-iteration-on-carma-6126241

Comment: Hm, the timings I see in the first post are measured in microseconds, not CPU cycles...

Comment: @user4422 By that reference, your 10us is actually quite fast.